# How to fix Runtime Exception (Coverage )

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hi I have error while running my application:

> (Coverage): Error during class instrumentation:
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>    java.io.IOException: Class not found
>
> Application: Failed to retrieve application JMX service URL

Have no idea how to fix it